# Mariadb unique constraint error ( duplicate entry) for two records with one space difference

Tags: sql, mariadb

Mariadb is version 10.0.23
I use below script to do testing

```
create table test(
username varchar(30)
,constraint UK_TEST unique (username);

insert into test values('name1');
1 row inserted.

insert into test values ('name1 ');
```

the second insert got error, the error message is

> duplicate entry 'name1 ' for key 'UK_TEST',

highlight, the second one is not same as the first one, the values have one more space in suffix

is there anyone can help me on this issue?

Comment: What collation are you using?

Comment: it's utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/varchar/), for VARCHAR and several other data types, trailing spaces are ignored in comparisons, including those used for unique constraints:

> Currently, all MariaDB collations are of type PADSPACE, meaning that
>   VARCHAR (as well as CHAR and TEXT values) are compared without regard
>   for trailing spaces. This does not apply to the LIKE pattern-matching
>   operator, which takes into account trailing spaces.
>
> If a unique index consists of a column where trailing pad characters
>   are stripped or ignored, inserts into that column where values differ
>   only by the number of trailing pad characters will result in a
>   duplicate-key error.

Answer (score 1):

You have marked "username" field as "UNIQUE". So, it will accept only unique values in that entire column. You are trying to insert duplicate values.

Read more at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html

Comment: two values are not same, the second one has one more space

Comment: Nope. It is still considered as same. In mine it gives error as "Duplicate entry 'name1 ' for key 'username'". You have to either some character after space or remove Unique for the column.

Comment: yes, it is still considered as same, I am doing data migration from oracle to mariadb, in oracle , they are not same, i mean is there any setting in mariadb can disable trim for constraint check?

Comment: No. there is nothing like that in Mariadb. You will have to manually do it.

Answer (score 1):

You run into this kind of problems when the username in database is either set to "UNIQUE" or set as "PRIMARY KEY". In your case it is **unique**, hence you cannot have two lines that share the same username which is very logic and correct.

I advise you to read more about mysql before going any forward.

Please read more here about primary key constraints: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html

Comment: two line is not same, the second one have one space in suffix